# How to determine if a Java Android Looper is busy

Tags: java, android

I have a simple handling of tasks on a separate thread.

```
class MyHandlerThread extends Thread {
    Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler();

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

How can I determine if the looper is currently busy handling messages or its message queue is empty and it is waiting for messages?I want to do that from another thread.

Basically, I want to know when the handler is done with a task that I have just submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use synchronized method to determine if thread is busy or not

Example:

```
public class MsLunch {
  private long c1 = 0;
  private long c2 = 0;
  private Object lock1 = new Object();
  private Object lock2 = new Object();

  public void inc1() {
      synchronized(lock1) {
          c1++;
      }
  }

  public void inc2() {
      synchronized(lock2) {
          c2++;
      }
  }
}
```

For More: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html